# Implement JS function in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

I have certain validation functions in a javascript file. I want to use them in my IOS app.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"validate" ofType:@"js"];

NSError* error;

NSString* validate = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

I have a **function keyDetails()** in validate.js

How do i create an instance of that function and call it.

Comment: Why would you want to run a JavaScript function? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im doing an app of a website which has a huge number of validations. Im trying to use the same javascript for validation here.

Comment: I would think it would be easier to do an HTML5 app wrapped in a UIWebView then.

Comment: yeah.. Tats a better idea.. But i need to learn about this..

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"validate" ofType:@"js"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"keyDetails()"];
```

The documentation for `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a).

Comment: how do i call a function in that jsvascript file??